# Implementing a Simulate function for a Boolean Circuit using an unordered map

Tags: c++, nodes, boolean-logic, unordered-map

I've been building a program which simulates a Boolean Circuit using a Graph. Each node in the graph has an ID, type of logical node (from a typedef that defined each node as Primary Input, And, Or, Not) as well as a vector for the nodes in and nodes out. I'll include the code for the header below:

```
#ifndef BOOLEAN_CIRCUIT_HH_
#define BOOLEAN_CIRCUIT_HH_
#include <string>
#include <vector>

enum class NodeType{PI, AND, OR, NOT};

class Node {
public:
    Node(unsigned id ,NodeType type);
    void addFanIn(Node * node);
    void addFanOut(Node * node);
    void printNode();

private:
    //bool flag;
    NodeType type;
    unsigned id;
    std::vector<Node*> fanIn;
    std::vector<Node*> fanOut;
};

class Boolean_Circuit{
public:
    Boolean_Circuit();
    Boolean_Circuit(std::string filename);
    ~Boolean_Circuit();
    void addNode( unsigned id, NodeType type, std::vector<unsigned> fanIn);
    //bool satisfy();
    bool simulate(std::vector<bool> inputs);
    int randomSuccessCount();
    int countLogicalNodes();
    void printCircuit();

protected:

private:
    bool evaluate(Node * node);
    std::vector<Node *> nodeList;
    std::string toString();//loop through nodelist
};
#endif // BOOLEAN_CIRCUIT_HH_
```

Currently I have the circuit building correctly and printing out as desired, now I just need to finish the evaluate and simulate methods in the Boolean_Circuit class. My suggested implementation by a professor was to use an unordered map to store the logical values for each node as simulate runs its inputs through the circuit. Current implementation:

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include "BooleanCircuit.hh"

Node::Node(unsigned idIn, NodeType typeIn){
    id = idIn;
    type = typeIn;
}

Boolean_Circuit::Boolean_Circuit(){}

Boolean_Circuit::Boolean_Circuit(std::string filename){
   std::ifstream in(filename);
   if(in.is_open()){
        std::string line;
        while(getline(in, line)){
            std::stringstream is(line);
            unsigned id;
            is>>id;
            std::string tag;
            is>>tag;
            NodeType type;
            if(tag == std::string("PI")) type = NodeType::PI;
            else if(tag == std::string("AND")) type = NodeType::AND;
            else if(tag == std::string("OR")) type = NodeType::OR;
            else if(tag == std::string("NOT")) type = NodeType::NOT;
            else{
                throw std::invalid_argument("Incorrect Inputs1");
            }
            std::vector<unsigned> fanIns;
            unsigned i;
            while(!is.eof()){
                is>>i;
                fanIns.push_back(i);
            }
            addNode(id, type, fanIns);

        }
   }
}

void Boolean_Circuit::addNode(unsigned id, NodeType type, std::vector<unsigned> fanIn){
    if (id != nodeList.size()){
        std::cout<< "ID = " << id << "NodeList Size = " << nodeList.size()<< std::endl;
        throw std::invalid_argument("Incorrect Inputs8");
    }

    if (type == NodeType::PI && fanIn.size()>0) throw std::invalid_argument("Incorrect Inputs2");
    else if (type == NodeType::AND && fanIn.size()<1) throw std::invalid_argument("Incorrect Inputs3");
    else if (type == NodeType::OR && fanIn.size()<1) throw std::invalid_argument("Incorrect Inputs4");
    else if (type == NodeType::NOT && fanIn.size()!=1) throw std::invalid_argument("Incorrect Inputs5");

    Node *newNode = new Node(id, type);
    for(size_t i = 0; i<fanIn.size(); i++){
        if(i>=id) throw std::invalid_argument("Incorrect Inputs6");
        newNode->addFanIn(nodeList[fanIn[i]]);
        nodeList[fanIn[i]]->addFanOut(newNode);
    }
    nodeList.push_back(newNode);

}

Boolean_Circuit::~Boolean_Circuit(){
    for(size_t i =0; i< nodeList.size();i++){
        delete(nodeList[i]);
     }
   nodeList.clear();
}


void Boolean_Circuit::printCircuit(){
    std::cout<< "Full circuit in order:"<<std::endl;
    for(size_t i = 0; i<nodeList.size(); i++){
        nodeList[i]->printNode();
    }
}

void Node::printNode(){
    std::string typeString;
    if(type == NodeType::PI) typeString = "PI";
    else if(type == NodeType::AND) typeString = "AND";
    else if(type == NodeType::OR) typeString = "OR";
    else if(type == NodeType::NOT) typeString = "NOT";
    else{
        throw std::invalid_argument("Incorrect Inputs7");
    }
    std::cout<< id << " " << typeString<< " In: ";
    for(size_t i=0; i<fanIn.size(); i++){
        std::cout<<fanIn[i]->id<<" ";
    }
    std::cout<<"Out: ";
    for(size_t i=0; i<fanOut.size(); i++){
        std::cout<<fanOut[i]->id<<" ";
    }
    std::cout<< "" << std::endl;
}

/*bool Boolean_Circuit::evaluate(Node node){ 
    if (!node) return 0;
    else if (node.type == NodeType::AND){
        for (int i=0; i<node.incoming.size(); i++){
            if(!node.incoming[i].status??) return 0; //relies on incoming returning bools
        }
        return 1;
    }

    else if(node.type == NodeType::OR){
       for (int i=0; i<node.incoming.size(); i++){
            if(node.incoming[i].status??) return 1; //relies on incoming returning bools
        }
        return 0;
    }

    else if (node.type == NodeType::NOT){
        //only ideas for this function rely on statuses
    }
}*/

bool Boolean_Circuit::simulate(std::vector<bool> inputs){
    std::unordered_map<unsigned, bool> mymap; //the unsigned is the node id, bool is the status of the node based of of inputs.
    return false;
}


void Node::addFanIn(Node * soloFan){
    fanIn.push_back(soloFan);
}

void Node::addFanOut(Node * soloFan){
    fanOut.push_back(soloFan);
}
```

Current main as well:

```
#include "BooleanCircuit.hh"
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
   if (argc >2){
    std::cout << "Too many arguments"<< std::endl;
    return -1;
   }
   else if (argc == 2){
       Boolean_Circuit circuit(argv[1]);
   }
   else{
       std::cout << "File name not provided" << std::endl;
       Boolean_Circuit circuit;
       circuit.addNode(0, NodeType::PI, {});
       circuit.addNode(1, NodeType::PI, {});
       circuit.addNode(2, NodeType::NOT, {0});
       circuit.addNode(3, NodeType::NOT, {1});
       circuit.addNode(4, NodeType::OR, {0,1});
       circuit.addNode(5, NodeType::OR, {0,3});
       circuit.addNode(6, NodeType::OR, {2,1});
       circuit.addNode(7, NodeType::OR, {2,3});
       circuit.addNode(8, NodeType::AND, {4,5,6,7});
       circuit.printCircuit();

   }
    return 0;
}
```

I'm unsure of how to implement the simulate and evaluate functions with the map as the structure is very new to me. Some help would be much appreciated. My desired functions should work as a pair, with evaluate helping to solve each node logically as simulate walks its inputs (given as a boolean vector) through the circuit. Using the unordered map as reference for status, how should I go about implementing?

If more details are needed as to design intentions let me know.

Comment: If you want to pair sim. data with nodes, using a map or unordered map would be one option. In either case, `Node*` may be used as key, the sim. state as value. Alternatively, you could use the node id as key. If you can ensure (or even force) that id's are consecutive numbers (at best starting with 0), you could use a vector instead. The vector would store the sim. states, where id (the key) is simply used as index. Access to vector is always **O(1)**. (Access to unordered map is in worst case **O(n)**, only with an ideal hash function **O(1)**. Access to map is in worst case **O(ld(n))**.)